# Microsoft Flight Simulator downloads stuck/loop

Tags: pc, microsoft-flight-simulator

I'm trying to run MS Flight Simulator in steam and while it is trying to install updates the downloads keep restarting. It will get through a few hundred MB or so and then reset back to the start of that stage. I've left it running for days but it just keeps happening.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why, but running [this command](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/xba_wowpc-xba_gowxb/microsoft-flight-simulator-2020-update-stuck-on/38cf27f1-38dd-46a4-bbaa-6c8bcb042de6?page=3):

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disable
```

in a command console fixed it for me.